# CoreML Tools: RuntimeError: PyTorch convert function for op 'intimplicit' not implemented

Tags: python, pytorch, coreml

I am trying to `coremltools.converters.convert` a traced PyTorch model and I got an error:
`PyTorch convert function for op 'intimplicit' not implemented`

I am trying to convert a RVC model from [github](https://github.com/RVC-Project/Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI.git).

I traced the model with `torch.jit.trace` and CoreML conversion fails. So I traced down the problematic part to the WN layer :
https://github.com/RVC-Project/Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI/blob/main/infer/lib/infer_pack/modules.py#L188

```py
import torch
import coremltools as ct
from infer.lib.infer_pack.modules import WN

model = WN(192, 5, dilation_rate=1, n_layers=16, gin_channels=256, p_dropout=0)
model.remove_weight_norm()
model.eval()

test_x = torch.rand(1, 192, 200)
test_x_mask = torch.rand(1, 1, 200)
test_g = torch.rand(1, 256, 1)

traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model,
  (test_x, test_x_mask, test_g),
  check_trace = True)

x = ct.TensorType(name='x', shape=test_x.shape)
x_mask = ct.TensorType(name='x_mask', shape=test_x_mask.shape)
g = ct.TensorType(name='g', shape=test_g.shape)

mlmodel = ct.converters.convert(traced_model,
    inputs=[x, x_mask, g])
```

I got an error `RuntimeError: PyTorch convert function for op 'intimplicit' not implemented.`

How could I modify the `WN::forward` so it does not generate an `intimplicit` operator so CoreML conversion could proceed?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the source of this issue.

Model is calling a function that has `@torch.jit.script` decorator:
https://github.com/RVC-Project/Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI/blob/main/infer/lib/infer_pack/commons.py#L108

Removing this decorator, `torch.jit.trace` no longer add an `intimplicit` operator in the trace and CoreML tools could succesfully convert the model.